# Flutter a widget that blocks taps but allows other gestures

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was just wondering if it is possible to a widget which allows scrolling but ignores taps.
I know how to use `IgnorePointer()` however this ignores all types of gestures. I would like a widget to be able to

1. Allow gestures such as scrolling and panning
2. But ignores taps

All help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a stack with a gesture detector on top, and having it change the current page/index? If it's on top, it should block anything below it. I'm not able to test this myself atm, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Will try however I'm not certain it will work in my specified case

Comment: @scottstoll2017 actually quick question do you know how to turn a page controllers value into an animation controller

Comment: what is your use case scenerio?

Comment: @scottstoll2017 Basically I want TabBarView where the second page overlaps the first page when scrolling over at the moment I am using a stack where the first page is behind the tabbarview then the second page is within the tabbarview so it scrolls from an empty container to page 2 with page 1 in the background

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can just put a GestureDetector on top and set only the onTap value to do nothing like: `onTap: () => {}`. It then will "catch" the tap but all other gestures will get through.

Comment: The PageView value changes instantly, so you aren't going to want to use that to animate.  It sounds like you might be able to use an AnimatedPositioned for your reveal. Also, buttons and GestureDetectors can respond to multiple kinds of events and you can simply not specify the ones you don't want. I use this in a lesson on GestureDetectors. And don't forget that you can have the GestureDetector on top and decide which variable it changes dynimically, causing different widgets to animate. You may also want to play with putting multiple GestureDetectors in a Row, triggering different things.